# Simple wp action & filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this is basic stuff, but I am just starting to learn action and filter hooks by building a simple plugin (everyone starts somewhere!) with a simple action hook to add content and a filter hook to change it.

Here is my action hook in the plugin file:

```
function sushi_add_a_title(){

    $title = 'hello world!';
    echo $title;
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'sushi_add_a_title' );
```

and the filter hook in functions.php:

```
function sushi_change_the_title( $title ){

    $title = 'hi world!';
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_head', ‘sushi_change_the_title' );
```

I was expecting the output to change from ‘hello world’ to ‘hi world!’... but no change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is wordpress aware of you custom filter ? in other words : have you included your custom filter in functions.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I have come up with a solution, and using str_replace.

```
function sushi_add_a_title(){
  $title = 'hello world!';
  echo apply_filters('a_nice_title' , $title );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'sushi_add_a_title');

add_filter('a_nice_title', 'replace_string');
function replace_string($title){
  $title = str_replace("hello world!", "Hi world!", $title);
  return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a "curly quote" (`‘`) in your `add_filter` line that might be breaking your PHP.

`add_filter( 'wp_head', ‘sushi_change_the_title' );`

Comment: With the correct ( ' ) format it still outputs 'hello world'.  I think I need to use  apply_filters('sushi_change_the_title', $title);  but not sure where